# Address in mailbox given [xxxxx] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2

Tags: php, laravel, email

upon exeucuting this:

```
Mail::send('mails.password', ['name' => $request->name, 'password' => $password], 
    function ($message) use ($request) {
        $message->from(getenv('MAIL_USERNAME'), 'Biofeedback');
        $message->to($request->email);
    }
);
```

my code throws an error. I'm using mailtrap, and that worked a week ago.

my .env:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=very_secret
MAIL_PASSWORD=very_secret
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

and I got an error, that

> Address in mailbox given [xxxxx] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.

why is that?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the issue is with this line here:

```php
$message->from(getenv('MAIL_USERNAME'), 'Biofeedback');
```

You are getting the `MAIL_USERNAME` value from the .env file. For mailtrap this is a bunch of letters and numbers. The error is saying that the email address you are providing does not comply with the RFC standards. A mailtrap SMTP username will not comply with the standard.

Try changing the line to a valid email and see if that solves the issue. It could look something like:

```php
$message->from('john@example.com', 'Biofeedback');
```

You could always then store that as a separate environment variable such as `FROM_EMAIL` and reference it as you previously did.

Also please ensure that `$request->email` is a valid email address.